# iPhone Phonegap Orientation problem

Tags: iphone, cordova

I make a simple application to iPhone with the phonegap library (Phonegap 0.9.6). I like to use the orientation function, but if I rotate the device, the screen don't change.
I tried a few things, but none worked.
I added these lines to `_Info.plist`:

```
   <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
   </array>
```

Next try to add these same lines to the `PhoneGap.plist`.
I try to use javascript, but don't work. Anybody know thw solution?

Comment: From what I can tell from the PhoneGap docs, orientationChanged isn't supported. I've seen mention of it before but may have been dropped in 1.0

Answer (score 2):

You need to add these to YOUR_APP_NAME-Info.plist :

**For iPad :**

```
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
```

**For iPhone :**

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the only thing that worked for me was to add this code to my js (outside of deviceready):

```
window.shouldRotateToOrientation = function(degrees) {
                return true;
            }
```

Then add to the xml:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="default" />
```

Comment: Still required as of Cordova 5.1.1, iOS 8 ... works on iPhone 6 and in simulator. (The plist solution from Ben Taliadoros also works, but this JavaScript is simpler.) BTW, similar Q/A here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999435/why-doesnt-my-cordova-phonegap-ios-app-rotate-when-the-device-rotates/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need to manually add to the plist file, as far as i can tell it's not copying from the config.xml due to a cordova issue.

So to get full orientation support on all your apple devices make sure the .plist file matches the below:

```
 <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
```