# How do I stop auto-rotate for Game Maker HTML 5 mobile?

Tags: html, phonegap, screen-rotation, game-maker

I have made my game with Game Maker HTML 5 and uploaded the file to Phone Gap. I have the game on my phone, but I don't want the game to auto-rotate. Can I put a code into my file to stop auto-rotate. If I have to edit my file in Phone Gap how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried on Game Maker, but this seems to me more about having proper settings in your *native* part of the project, rather than Game Maker of PhoneGap.

Have you already looked at these SO questions for [PhoneGap on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793639/iphone-phonegap-orientation-problem) and [PhoneGap on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801128/phonegap-forcing-landscape-orientation)?