# PhoneGap - Forcing Landscape orientation

Tags: android, cordova, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

I started looking into PhoneGap yesterday and created a simple "marble" rolling around while tilting the phone. I am currently developing on Android but I want the orientation to stay as landscaping instead of moving when the phone gets spun around. Is there a way of doing this?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.phonegap.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".App" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
            <intent-filter></intent-filter> 
        </activity> 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Code:

```
package com.phonegap.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class App extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: After Apache Cordova 3.0 release modifying the AndroidManifest.xml will break the Cordova development workflow. Use a plugins instead. See possible duplicated response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294090/cordova-3-1-oriention-not-working/21165941#21165941

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, where you have declared your activity, just add the above line.

For example:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: I added it to the wrong activity tag so this was a winner! cheers

Comment: Anton's answer is a better choice

Answer (score 31):

The correct way to do this for all devices is to configure config.xml

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />

<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Comment: Phonegap seems to be ignoring these settings for me, regardless of their value.

Comment: Ideally, this would work perfectly across all PhoneGap platforms. My theory is that the PhoneGap WebView may be locked to a certain orientation, but its containing Activity rotates according to the properties in AndroidManifest.xml. However, I still think this could be fixed by PhoneGap; PhoneGap could edit AndroidManifest.xml, or the DroidGap class could manage/prevent rotation.

Comment: @apanosa: this solution regard the phonegap build. I confirm that it does work on ios 7.x and android 2.x right now with phonegap 3.4.0.

Comment: This is right way to define orientatian. Thanks Anton

Answer (score 7):

It is very simple, you need to add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in your `AndroidManifest`.xml file.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".LogUploaderActivity" android:label="Log Uploader" android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this in your activity. Inside `onCreate()` and before setContentView.

```
// keeps the screen orientation in Landscape mode
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: not sure on where to put this, I have not touched java before.

Comment: @PhilJackson Inside the main activity's onCreate() method :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe important to mention because i did not know it:

If you use the online phonegap apk converter with **hydration enabled** to your application, u'll have to **rebuild** your app completly instead of just update it. This will help you also with preferences like "orientation" or "fullscreen" !