# phonegap orientation landscape only

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to set the orientation to landscape in my phonegap application. I don't know anything about java, so I don't use `AndroidManifest.xml` file in my project since it's generated when I type the command `sudo phonegap run android` which I never uses.

When I finish my html files, I upload them to my account on [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com) and the website does the rest of work(building the apk from my html,css&js files).

The only `xml` file that I change is `config.xml` file. I change the orientation mode in it.

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

and I have the following meta tags In my project

```
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
```

The problem is that the orientation doesn't become landscape only when I install the game on my device. Is there something that I miss?

Comment: You can find orientation information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode)

Comment: @BenoîtbadetitouVerhaeghe All of the solutions there are for android programmers. I know only in web developing.

Comment: How is your folder structure when you're compressing the files to upload to bulild.phonegap.com?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhoneGap - Forcing Landscape orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801128/phonegap-forcing-landscape-orientation)